# Convert pdf from link to image and then share

Tags: android, image, pdf, android-studio, share

I am searching for a library, sdk whatever, which converts a pdf (from a link) to an image, and then I want to share this image without leaving any trails (random png images left of the conversion or a downloaded pdf file somewhere). Has anyone any ideas on what and how I should do this?

  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you open pdf into webview then follow this step

```
WebView pdfWebView;
Bitmap pdfBitMap;


pdfWebView.buildDrawingCache();
pdfBitMap = pdfWebView.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Is there a way to save the bitmap without actually _opening_ the PDF? (I'm using another plugin for that)

Comment: I think you have to do with the help of picaso library , not sure Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);